# Print recursively without any loops

Tags: java, recursion

Didn't find any other post like this so i had to ask.
It is easy to print anything... but when you're not allowed to use iterative methods then things get tricky.

My problem is that i have two methods in one class. This class has a string that should be printed in reverse.. simple with iterative methods but not when char and int gets in the way,

I have tried to count the amout of integers to the amout of char in a string and then use the other method to take that same string and count of int to print it out in reverse.

NOTE: Need these two methods with string and int as parameters.

What am i doing wrong?

```
public class PrintRecursive {
private static int j;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "Hello Everyone!";

    print(str, 0);
    System.out.println(); // Line break
    printReverse(str, 0);
}

private static void printReverse(String str, int i) {
    char ch = (char) i;
    if (ch == ' ') {

    } else
        while (str.contains(str)) {
            i += str.charAt(ch);
        }
}

private static void print(String str, int i) {

    while (str.equals(i)) {
        System.out.println(str.charAt(j--));
    }
}

}
```

Outcome:

Hello Everyone!
!enoyrevE olleH

ALSO: Note that i guess that i should be talking to the methods directly instead of my "private int j".

My code atm is not recursive!!!!!!! But i want it to be but i cannot figure out a way of doing so.

Comment: Pass in an int equal to the length of the `String` minus one, and then while the int is more than or equal to zero, print the char at the int, and then recurse passing one minus the int

Comment: Try to create a recursive method

Comment: you never set `j` to anything

Comment: `str.equals(i)` will always return false. You're comparing a `String` and an int

Comment: You are not doing anything with i in print method.You are comparing Hello Everyone with i.

Comment: You print method will not print anything.Also your printReverse is infinite loop since str.contains(str) will always be true

Comment: Your title says *"Print recursively"*, but I see no attempt at making any recursive calls in your code. You do know what "recursive" means, right?

Comment: Well that is the thing... i need it to be recursive!!!!

Comment: So, why don't your code have a recursive method? I think you need to study about it. You will not learn from getting someone to do your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive approach (where one letter is printed in each recursion step) could look like this:

```
private static void print(String s, int i) {
    if(i == s.length() - 1)   
        System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
    else {
        System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        print(s, i+1);
    }
}

private static void printReverse(String s, int i) {
    if(i == 0)
        System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
    else {
        System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        printReverse(s, i-1);
    }
}
```

You would call it as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    print("abcd", 0);
    printReverse("abcd", 3);
}
```

`print()` is passed the integer 0 as a starting value and `printReverse()` is passed the length of the string - 1, which is the index of the last letter.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   printStringInReverse("Hello", "Hello".length() - 1);
}

public static void printStringInReverse(String s, int x) {
    if (x < 0) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(s.charAt(x));
    printStringInReverse(s, x - 1);
}
```

Note that I start the method with `if (x < 0)`. This is a "base case", the condition that stops the recursion. Then I print the char at index `x`, and call the method again, but decrementing `x`. This means that the next call will print the character before.

In fact, this method don't need to have an int parameter:

```
public static void printStringInReverse(String s) {
    if (s.equals("")) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(s.charAt(s.length() - 1));
    printStringInReverse(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1), x);
}
```

The second approach is more similar to how recursion is used in functional languages like Haskell.

Next time you are asked to write a recursive method, here are some tips:

- think of the base case(s). What are the cases where you don't need to call the method again?
- If it is not one of the base cases, do part of the job with part of the input
- Call the method itself and pass the rest of the input.
- Keep in mind that you want the input to be reduced to one of the base cases.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues here. First, in your `print` method, you start off by comparing a string to an integer in your while loop condition. Also, inside your while loop, you decrement a variable `j` when I believe you should be using variable `i` here since it's being passed in. So this is probably what you were trying to achieve with `print`,

```
private static void print(String str, int i) {
    while (i < str.length()) {
        System.out.print(str.charAt(i++));
    }
}
```

Now with `printReverse`, you start off by casting the int variable `i` that is passed in to a char and compare that to `' '`. There's no point to doing this because any valid integer passed in will never equal `' '` after a char cast. I think what you meant to do in this method is pretty much the same thing as `print` but in reverse. Therefore, all you would need to change is the while loop and the print statement,

```
private static void printReverse(String str, int i) {
    while (i < str.length()) {
        System.out.print(str.charAt(str.length() - i++ - 1));
    }
}
```

Note that if you want to this recursively, you need to establish a base case and a recursive call to your function. For example with `print` you can make the base case the same thing as the while loop condition from above, stop calling `print` when `i >= str.length()`, and the call to the method itself can be made after you've printed out the character at index `i` while simultaneously incrementing `i`,

```
private static void print(String str, int i) {
    if (i >= str.length()){
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(str.charAt(i++));
    print(str, i);
}
```

The same logic can be applied for `printReverse`,

```
private static void printReverse(String str, int i) {
    if (i >= str.length()) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(str.charAt(str.length() - i++ - 1));
    printReverse(str, i);
}
```